# Verifying password in Python sqlite3 and tkinter

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

```
import sqlite3
from tkinter import *


def clear_fields():
    enter1.delete(0, END)
    enter2.delete(0, END)


conn = sqlite3.connect("main.db")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute(
    """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS admins(
        admin_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        name text,
        password text
        )"""
)
conn.commit()


def pass_check():
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM admins")
    chck = c.fetchall()
    for i in chck:
        if i[(1)] == enter1.get() and i[(2)] == enter2.get():
            break
            print("login sucess")
        else:
            print("Accses Denied")


root = Tk()
root.geometry("250x180+550+200")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.title("Admin Login")
root.iconbitmap("login.ico")

labl1 = Label(text="User name: ")
labl1.place(x=10, y=10)
labl2 = Label(text="Password: ")
labl2.place(x=10, y=70)
usr = ""
pas = ""
enter1 = Entry()
enter1.place(x=80, y=10)
enter2 = Entry(show="*")
enter2.config()
enter2.place(x=80, y=70)

ok_btn = Button(text="Login", width=6, height=1, command=pass_check)
ok_btn.place(x=150, y=100)
clear_btn = Button(text="Clear", width=6, height=1, command=clear_fields)
clear_btn.place(x=80, y=100)

root.mainloop()
```

in my terminal if i enter the right username and password i get
login success
Access Denied

and if i enter the wrong credentials i get
Access Denied
Access Denied
I only have 2 admins in the admin table in the database
i think the problem is in the for loop statement but i don't seem to know what it is.

Comment: Remove `break` from the for loop

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You cannot get "login sucess" because of the `break` statement.  You can check the  validity of the credentials using SQL directly instead of getting all the records from the table.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why you get "login sucess" because of the `break` statement. You need to call `break` after `print(...)`.  Also you need to call `print("Access Denied")` in the `else` block of `for`:

```py
def pass_check():
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM admins")
    chck = c.fetchall()
    for i in chck:
        if i[(1)] == enter1.get() and i[(2)] == enter2.get():
            print("login sucess")
            break
    else:
        print("Accses Denied")
```

However, you don't need to get all the records from the database table, just use SQL to check the validity of the credentials directly:

```py
def pass_check():
    c.execute("SELECT 1 FROM admins WHERE name = ? and password = ?",
              (enter1.get(), enter2.get()))
    result = c.fetchone()
    if result:
        print("Login Success")
    else:
        print("Access Denied")
```

Comment: thanks for explaining that to me, i'm a self learner just starting the journey, people like you makes it much fun, thanks a lot.